# Leetcode Count of Smaller Numbers After Self solution

Tags: python, algorithm, tree

Question [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/count-of-smaller-numbers-after-self/description/#)

> You are given an integer array `nums` and you have to return a new
>   `counts` array. The `counts` array has the property where `counts[i]` is the
>   number of smaller elements to the right of `nums[i]`.

Solution is done using customized BST where `count` stores the total number of elements lesser than current element found from left to right.

```
class Solution:
    def countSmaller(self, nums):
        class Node:
            def __init__(self, val):
                self.val = val
                self.left = None
                self.right = None
                self.count = 0

        def bst_insert(root, val, result, count):
            if not root:
                root = Node(val)
                root.left = None
                root.right = None
                result.append(count)
                return root
            if val > root.val:
                root.right = bst_insert(root.right, val, result, root.count + 1 + count)
            else:
                root.count += 1
                root.left = bst_insert(root.left, val, result, count)
            return root

        root = None
        result = []
        for num in nums[::-1]:
            if not root:
                root = Node(num)
                result.append(0)
            else:
                bst_insert(root, num, result, 0)
        return result[::-1]
```

Comment: What is a "BST"?

Comment: @benrudgers Binary Search Tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first advice is to remove the class. In python you should use classes when it makes sense to do so, but you don't need to.

Next, your `bst_insert` has redundant code. `root.left = None` and `root.right = None` are already done in your constructor, so you don't need to duplicate them.

The last piece of advice is to use `reversed(nums)` instead of `num[::-1]` as the former does not make a copy, which should be faster and use less memory.

Other than that this looks pretty good.

Comment: If i remove class then i will get compilation error. Can you modify this https://ideone.com/9dHWDS and let me know what you mean?

Comment: https://ideone.com/ZUhsEK

Comment: That class is mandatory in leetcode.